# Do not start guest after virt-install

Tags: libvirt, virt-install

I like to set up a new guest but do not want to start it immediately.
I use `virt-install` with these options:

```
virt-install \
    --connect qemu:///system \
    --import \
    --virt-type kvm \
    --name somevm \
    --os-variant win7 \
    --memory 2048 \
    --vcpus 1 \
    --disk /home/bla/VirtualMachines/somevm.qcow2,format=qcow2,device=disk \
    --network network=default \
    --noautoconsole \
    --sound default
```

But `virt-install` will always start the VM. I can not find any option in the man page to disable the automatic start.
I would rather not call `virsh destroy somevm` right after the install, although the VM will probably not be booted up yet...
Is it possible to prevent the start of the guest with virt-install or is there another tool which can do the same but do not start the guest?

I also found some kind of workaround: instead of using `--import`, you can install the VM with `--pxe`. If no PXE server is available, then this should give enough time to destroy the guest using `virsh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--print-xml` option to virt-install might get closer to what you want. You could then feed the XML it prints into the `virsh define` command to create, but not start, the guest.

Alternatively checkout the `virt-xml` tool which is simply a friendly way to build up an XML document from args like those you'd give to virt-install

Comment: --print-xml looks very promising! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the option `--noreboot`

```
virt-install \
   ..
   ..
   --noautoconsole \
   --video vga \
   --memballoon none \
   --noreboot
```

UPDATE:
Added the `--memballoon` option for those who spin up a Windows VM. Memballoon doesn't really work on Windows.

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent option in Virt-manager?

Comment: Nope, I don't use Virt-manager, sorry

Comment: This is really the real answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned a case that might be useful for your goal in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762576/21183541):

In essence, if you have an existing disk image with everything already installed (you might have created this before, or cloned it from an existing KVM guest), stored in `/var/lib/libvirt/images/debian10.qcow2`, you can automate the creation of a new KVM virtual machine by importing that image with `virt-install` and its options `--noautoconsole`, e.g.,

`virt-install --virt-type kvm --name debian10 --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/debian10.qcow2 --import --os-variant debian10 --vcpus 1 --memory 1024 --noautoconsole`

The domain (or the virtual machine) named debian10 will be created without asking for any interaction, `virt-install` will exit quickly as mentioned in its manual

> --noautoconsole: Don't automatically try to connect to the guest console...
> Note, virt-install exits quickly when this option is specified...

Since you have the image with everything already installed, the termination of `virt-install` causes no problem, rather a desired behaviour in this case.
Afterwards, you can shutdown the guest VM with the `virsh destroy` or `virsh shutdown` command. At this point, you can modify the XML file of the guest VM gracefully with `virsh edit`, or in a direct manner on its source file (usually stored at /etc/libvirt/qemu/)